# Get all opened Conversation using Lync 2010 SDK

Tags: c#, lync

I want to get all opened conversations using `Lync` 2010 SDK and save them using Code.

Here is my code

```
LyncClient lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
ConversationManager conversationManager = lyncClient.ConversationManager;
```

Could you tell me what to do after that?

Comment: Does this API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationmanager.conversations_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt(v=office.14).aspx helps

Comment: Hi, Abhinav, thanks for your reply , Is it possible to save Conversations through code of all Open Windows. The task that we do by pressing Ctrl+S i want to achieve it through code.

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently started working on a similar project. You can enumerate all conversations using the ConversationManager.Conversations property.

```
    Dim lc As LyncClient
    lc = LyncClient.GetClient

    For Each c In lc.ConversationManager.Conversations

    Next()
```

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get all of the text out of a conversation.